# Referencing Azure DevOps Variable Group values in a YAML Pipeline

Tags: variables, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have created three Variable Groups in Azure DevOps which comprise of three variables:

- WebApp-DEV
- WebApp-QA
- WebApp-Prod

Each variable group has a variable named environment whose value is appropriately named to correspond with the environment.

What I'd like to do now is reference each environment variable in my Azure Pipeline yaml file. The screenshot below depicts how I'm currently referencing the variable group WebApp-DEV in the pipeline DEV stage.

[image]

How do I however call or reference the environment values for each variable group, as per the above depiction for WebApp-DEV? In other words, what is the syntax required to reference the value of my variable from a variable group?

Answer (score 1):

When you reference variable group all variables from variable group are available in the scope which you reference variable group. So ig you have `WebApp-Dev` referenced on job level you can use variables from this group in this job. And the syntax, well if you have `env` variable defined in variable group it should be `$(env)` and just it.

```yaml
stages:
- stage: DEV
  jobs:
  - job: DEV
    variables:
    - group: WebApp-Dev
    steps:
    - script: echo '$(env)' #env comes from WebApp-Dev variable group
```